# No arg not getting generated using Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok in one of Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
@Data
@Builder
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String courseEnrolled;
    private String rollNo;
```

When I run this, I am getting following error:

```
java: constructor Student in class com.example.student.entity.Student cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
```

I tried to provide default constructor `@NoArgsConstructor` , then it throws compiler error that no-arg constructor is already defined.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. Can anyone guide as to why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue you need to use `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` with the @Builder annotation because this one it requires all-args constructor to function properly:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@Builder` which automatically also generates an All-Args-Constructor with access-level package-private if there are no other constructors, see [lombok-doc for builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).
However, you also use `@Data`, which generates a `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, see [lombok-doc for data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)  (which in your case, is a no-args-constructor, because there are no final fields).
It appears like `@Builder` is not generating a constructor because you already have the no-args-constructor from `@Data`.

**Solution 1**: `@Builder` can be put on a constructor, not just a class, and that would clear the confusion about what constructor it should use.

**Solution 2**: Don't put `@Data` on the class, because it is just a shortcut for other annotations.

On another note: By putting `@Data` on an Entity-class, you are creating some problems, so I would go with Solution 2, see here: https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/

Comment: The explanation is correct, but the answer doesn't appear to include the actual answer. Which is to explicitly choose the constructors you want here; you'll need `@AllArgsConstructor` for the builder, and `@NoArgsConstructor` for your own needs.